# Как правильно перейти с EAGER на LAZY

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Мне надо поменять стратегию загрузки с FetchType.EAGER на FetchType.LAZY. У меня реализовано что то вроде с сайта со sping secur c возможностью логина. Дальше идет панель админа (В случае если зашел админ), на которой видно таблицу всех пользователей. Напротив каждого пользователя есть кнопки удаления и редактирования. Собственно при попытки редактирования появляется ошибка org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session.При переходе она тоже была, погуглив проблему изменил один из методов в сервисе.

```
    @Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user =  userDao.getUserByName(name);
    user.getAuthorities().size();
    return user;
}
```

Никак не могу понять, в чем у меня может быть проблема, не могу найти нормальной инфы по поводу этой ошибки. Дальше приложу код моделей юзера и роли а также сервиса. `@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", unique = true)
private String name;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
public Set<Role> roles;


public User() {
}

public User(String name, String password, Set<Role> roles) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.roles = roles;
}

public User(String name, String password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.roles = roles;
}

public User(Long id, String name, String password, Set<Role> roles) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.roles = roles;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return roles;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

}

Role

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "role")
private String role;

@Transient
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles") // указывает на поле с коллекцией владеемых объектов в классе владельце
private List<User> users;

public Role() {
}

public Role(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public Role(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Role(Long id, String role) {
    this.id = id;
    this.role = role;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return role;
}

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return role;
}
```

}

service

```
@Service
```

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {

```
private final UserDao userDao;

@Autowired
public UserServiceImpl(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void createUser(User user) {
    userDao.createUser(user);
}

@Override
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return userDao.getAllUsers();
}

@Override
public User getUserById(long id) {
    return userDao.getUserById(id);
}

@Override
public User getUserByName(String name) {
    return userDao.getUserByName(name);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void updateUser(User user) {
    userDao.updateUser(user);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteUser(long id) {
    userDao.deleteUser(id);
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user =  userDao.getUserByName(name);
    user.getAuthorities().size();
    return user;
}
```

}

Comment: Небольшая ошибка в заголовке. При переходе была такая же ошибка, не работал метод который бы показывал таблицу. Путем поиска решения этой проблемы в интернете, удалось решить эту проблема, но возникла новая.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821695/how-to-fix-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самая частая причина возникновения `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` - обращение к непроинициализированной коллекции за пределами сессии (== транзакции), в которой была загружена сущность. В вашем коде эта коллекция явно инициализируется только в методе `UserServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(...)`, в остальных методах - нет. Необходимо либо явно проинициализировать коллекцию ролей в каждом из методов `UserServiceImpl` до того, как вернуть объект `user` клиенту (== FetchType.EAGER), либо расширить область действия транзакции на то место, где осуществляется редактирование объекта `user`, либо ввести промежуточный слой представления (dto) для объектов `User`